# Content Security Policy with FluentUI-React-Electron-Forge

Tags: electron, content-security-policy, webpack-5, electron-forge, fluent-ui

With `index.html` :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content-src='static2.sharepointonline.com';
      script-src-elem 'static2.sharepointonline.com';
      img-src 'static2.sharepointonline.com';
      style-src 'static2.sharepointonline.com';
      font-src 'https://static2.sharepointonline.com;
      connect-src https: http:"
    >
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" style="height: 100%;" style-src="../../assets/fonts/" 'self' data:></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In `index.tsx` :

```
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Icons"
initializeIcons("https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/icons/", { disableWarnings: true })
```

I get this message:

> Refused to load the font '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
> data:". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

```
"@fluentui/react": "^8.80.0"
"react": "^18.1.0"
node: v16.15.1
O.S. : Ubuntu 20.04
```

Update 1)

I've found in the `Electron docs` this suggestions:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/security#csp-http-header

I then added this snippet into `main` :

```
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        'Content-Security-Policy': ['default-src \'none\'', 'script-src-elem \'static2.sharepointonline.com\'']
      }
    })
  })
```

But I get this errors:

```
    Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'static2.sharepointonline.com'
```

Update 2):

Now in `index.html` :

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content-src=static2.sharepointonline.com;
  script-src-elem static2.sharepointonline.com;
  img-src static2.sharepointonline.com;
  style-src static2.sharepointonline.com;
  font-src https://static2.sharepointonline.com;
  connect-src https: http:"
>
```

Here: https://content-security-policy.com/#source_list
I read : `* : Wildcard, allows any URL except data: blob: filesystem: schemes.`

So... I tried to put in `main`:

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, 
  callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        'Content-Security-Policy': ['default-src \'*\'',  'style-src-
attr \'*\'', 'script-src-elem \'*\'' ]
      }
    })
  })
```

the previous error disappear but the app doesnt work and I get these two errors, which I tried, without succeeding, to solve :
[image]

Update 3)

As in https://webpack.js.org/guides/csp/#examples I tried to set `__webpack_nonce__` in `webpack.main.config.js` (I'm using `Electron Forge` )  .

I've put in this way:

```
const rules = require('./webpack.rules');
const plugins = require('./webpack.plugins');

rules.push({
  test: /\.ts$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }],
});

module.exports = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the 
first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: {
    main: './src/main/index.ts',
  },
  __webpack_nonce__ =  
'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=',
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    //rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
    rules,
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css', '.json'],
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      'stream': require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      'buffer': require.resolve('buffer'),
      'util': require.resolve('util'),
      'assert': require.resolve('assert'),
      'http': require.resolve('stream-http'),
      'url': require.resolve('url'),
      'https': require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      'os': require.resolve('os-browserify'),
      'path': require.resolve('path-browserify')
    },
  },
};
```

In `index.html` :

```
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, 
callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        //'Content-Security-Policy': ['default-src \'*\'',  'style-src-attr \'*\'', 'script-src-elem \'*\'' ]
        'Content-Security-Policy0: [
          'default-src \'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=\'',
          'style-src-attr \'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=\'',
          'script-src-elem \'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=\'' 
        ] 
      }
    })
  })
```

But I get

```
An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Invalid shorthand property initializer
/home/raphy/FPlayground/webpack.main.config.js:18
  __webpack_nonce__ =   
'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=',

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

Update 4)

Now... I'm having a real strange error and situation.

With in `main`:

```
   session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        'Content-Security-Policy': [
          'default-src \'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=\'',
          'style-src-attr \'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=\'',
          'script-src-elem \'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=\''
        ]
      }
    })
```

in `webpack.plugins.js` :

```
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({

    options: {
      __webpack_nonce__ : 'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=',
    },

  }),
```

and in `index.html` :

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content-src 'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';
      script-src-elem 'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';
      img-src 'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';
      style-src 'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';
      font-src 'nonce-c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';
      connect-src https: http:"
    >
```

[image]

Where to specify Content-Security-Policy? In `package.json` as suggested here: [React Electron App - React Leaftlet Content Security Policy errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705751/react-electron-app-react-leaftlet-content-security-policy-errors) ? or in `webpack.plugins.js` ?

How to make it work?

Comment: Thank you @spender for your kind editing help

Comment: No problem  As I understand it, only special values like `'self'`, `'unsafe-inline'`, `'unsafe-eval'` should be quoted.

Comment: Also worth checking that there isn't a CSP passed in the http headers as this will always take prio over a `<meta>` CSP and can't be relaxed (i.e. can only be made stricter) via the `<meta>` CSP.

Comment: @spender CSP passed in the http headers in an `Electron` app? Actually I do not know where to look for  . I search info

Comment: @spender After reading `electron docs` I updated my StackOverflow post above

Comment: Once again, only special values like `'self'`, `'unsafe-inline'`, `'unsafe-eval'` should be quoted. URLs should not have quotes. So, in your second example, for instance, `'script-src-elem \'static2.sharepointonline.com\''` should be `'script-src-elem static2.sharepointonline.com'`

Comment: @spender with `'Content-Security-Policy': ['default-src \'*\'',  'style-src-attr \'*\'', 'script-src-elem \'*\'' ]` I still get ` CSP blocks inline execution of scripts and stylesheets`

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite few hours in this hurdle...

Bu, now, with in `package.json` :

```
  "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "devContentSecurityPolicy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self'; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/icons/; connect-src 'self';",
```

`./src/app/index.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" style="height: 100%;" style-src="../../assets/fonts/" 'self' data:></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and commented `__webpack_nonce__' option in` webpack.plugin.js'

it seems working fine

I have to thank @spender for having highlighted some errors I made